# How cart works in react native application that use firebase as backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building food ordering app using react native and firebase as backend server, I am facing a problem as it is my first experience with such application. So, after  food items selected will be added to cart, So my question is how this actually work?

Do I need to store this items in database I am using or just store it using `AsyncStorage` library while user logged in of course will use also `redux` to asynchronies item in cart whenever I navigate.

I hope someone can help me or provided me with some tutorials as all what I found it is only about how to add item to cart but they didn't mentioned anything about database if should also be stored there or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-ridge-state for cart functionality you can find it here [React ridge state](https://github.com/web-ridge/react-ridge-state)

and here is the code reference make a new js file and paste these two lines there you can import this in your product page and use it by calling cartProducts.get() and cartProducts.set()

```
import {newRidgeState} from 'react-ridge-state'
export const cartProducts = newRidgeState([]);
```

although its named as react-ridge-state it works in react-native like a charm

Comment: great, how about when close the app does it keep added items in cart or need to add again

Comment: No you can save it in async storage for that